# eGPU Setup on Deepin 15.2 (Ubuntu Based)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have an eGPU setup of nVidia GT710 via Express Card. When linux boots up my main laptop screen works but the secondary screen doesn't work.
I am using opensource drivers as both cards require different proprietary drivers. Both the devices are recognized.

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GT218M [NVS 3100M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:32 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:7000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d307ffff
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: NVIDIA Corporation
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:33 memory:e2000000-e2ffffff memory:d8000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:e3000000-e307ffff
```

When I tried to boot via UBUNTU Usb both the displays work. Would someone be able to help me out? I like Deepin's look and feel more than any other distro.

I previously installed nVidia Drivers (to no avail) and I have nVidia X Server Settings app. It lists both of my GPUs.

[image: Main Panel]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can anyone help?